# What does "orphan" mean in the "cdk diff"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

`cdk diff` shows the befow diff because I am removing some of the services. Notice that the last line shows `orphan` in the end. What does that mean? Will this continue to occupy space even after the `cdk deploy`.

```
[-] AWS::IAM::Role myServiceTask77c32c53ac6143bcb908adfc54ce2977/TaskRole myServiceTask77c32c53ac6143bcb908adfc54ce2977TaskRoleD0FE40D9 destroy
[-] AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition myServiceTask77c32c53ac6143bcb908adfc54ce2977 myServiceTask77c32c53ac6143bcb908adfc54ce29777B67982E destroy
[-] AWS::Logs::LogGroup myServiceTask77c32c53ac6143bcb908adfc54ce2977/myServiceContainer77c32c53ac6143bcb908adfc54ce2977/LogGroup myServiceTask77c32c53ac6143bcb908adfc54ce2977rmsisServiceContainer77c32c53ac6143bcb908adfc54ce2977LogGroupAC4EC700 orphan
```

Here is my relevant cdk code,

```js
const container = taskDefinition.addContainer("myServiceContainer", {
  image: "...",
  logging: ecs.LogDriver.awsLogs({
    streamPrefix: "myServiceContainer",
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means it is a resource that will be deleted from CloudFormation, but retained in the account.

When `ecs.LogDriver.awsLogs` isn't given a `logGroup: ILogGroup` [prop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.AwsLogDriverProps.html), the CDK helpfully creates a LogGroup.  This CDK-created LogGroup has the default [Removal Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_logs.LogGroup.html#removalpolicy), which is `RemovalPolicy.RETAIN`. And default [RetentionDays](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_logs.LogGroup.html#retention) is set to RetentionDays.TWO_YEARS. The [RETAIN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.RemovalPolicy.html#retain) behaviour will "orphan" the resource:

> This uses the 'Retain' DeletionPolicy, which will cause the resource to be retained in the account, but orphaned from the stack.

If you want to have CloudFormation tidy up, pass your own LogGroup to `awsLogs` with `RemovalPolicy.DESTROY`.